# In light of how rare the "Reversal" badge is

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

I think it should be called "Reversal!"

With only 187 of these things in circulation, I think it could use the emphasis that it's an amazing occurrence.

Comment: And the exclamation point is for what, the emphasis of the amazing occurrence?

Comment: No, thanks. I don't want badges yelling at me.

Comment: There's only one though, so it wouldn't be "badges yelling at you". Just "badge". ;)

Comment: Nah, you can earn `Reversal` several times, and the multiplier will only emphasize the exclamation :)

Comment: Someone needs to write a highly voted answer here. Possible Reversal! badge on the cards.

Comment: Have you checked the occurrence of the badge on **other sites** yet? These badges are not unique to Stack Overflow. Take a look at their frequency on Meta sites, or on Meta.Stackexchange.com for example. Here on this very *young* Meta.SO we already have [82 of them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal).

Comment: That's pretty interesting, actually. :)

Answer (score 24):

Exclamation points are still too boring. I suggest an irony mark: "Reversal[image: irony point]"

Also, [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) and [Constable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable) should be called "Precognitive[image: acclamation point]" and "Constable[image: authority point]", respectively.

Comment: I only upvoted to try to get you a reversal badge for this question (although still a ways yo go at the time of this upvote)

Comment: Ordinarily, I would delete this question. But maybe Michael will get a reversal for it. :D

Comment: Go Reversal!  You can do it! :)

Comment: @Almo considering it has upvoted answers, you couldn't delete even if you wanted too.

Comment: Oh really. That's interesting. So... what's the deal with all the questions on SO that have generated "Reversal!" badges that have been removed? Hmm it says I can delete the question. But if I do it a lot, I could be blocked from asking.

Comment: Meta.SO badges are worth almost as much as Meta.SO reputation!

Comment: @Almo finally it happened!

Answer (score 13):

Make it so each time you get it it adds an exclamation mark.

1. Reversal
2. ¡Reversal!
3. ¡¡Reversal!!
4. ¡¡¡Reversal!!!
5. ¡¡¡¡Reversal!!!!
6. ¡¡¡¡¡Reversal!!!!!

Comment: Okay, you win. I'll boot BlazBlue and go train with Hakumen now :p

Comment: Or `¡Reversal` possibly in keeping with the badge name.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it should be:  ¡lɐsɹǝʌǝɹ